# AWS + Docker + Puma + Rails + S3 , broken upload after few hours of uploading

Tags: ruby-on-rails, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, docker, puma

I have a fully working rails application that I recently migrated to ECS at AWS.

I mean for the first hour or so, I see no problem, then the upload with fog and carrierwave gem just stops with no logs what so ever.

At this moment i failed back to my servers where I have this app installed directly on top of CentOS server served by NGINX + Passanger module behind haproxy loadbalancer.

With this setup I can run for months without restart and everything is working just fine.

Now I took the same code, moved it to a docker container with base image of Alpine linux (tested with 3.3 and 3.4), run it with Puma web server gem on top of EC2 instance. When i start it, everything is working and application feels faster, but after some time (not always the same period) carrierwave + fog upload to S3 is not working anymore (also it is not effected by number of uploaded files. i can upload 1000 and it is working for few hours or i can upload just one and it is also working just few hours).

I don't get any error message, I dont get any log in the app, all I see is the loading gif that never disappears.

I have done lot of testing already, same result. At this moment and I am planning on moving from Puma to different web server, from Alpine linux to CentOS and see at which stage of migration this stops to happen (hopefully it will).

Also I am sorry but for now I won't share any code as I know the code is working fine, but if anything is needed, I will be happy to copy paste it over here.

I just hope that there is someone with the same resolved issue as I were not able to find anything on the Internet.

Thank you all

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was with the cache that shared the memory with the application. So when application was running and I started to upload multiple images at the same time and amazon task was limited to 512MB, then this started to fail during uploads. Increasing the size of the task to 1.5GB and running it on at least small instance with 2G of ram fixed the issue.